# ОДИН цикл из двух условий

Tags: c#

Есть такой код:

```
static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6 && 6 < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

но мне надо чтобы он построчно отображал сперва от 0 до 6 и потом от 6 до 10
я знаю что можно написать

```
static void Main()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

но мне такой вариант не годится так как вместо && должно быть слово and, один цикл а выполняет И от ..до.. И от..до

Comment: Из условия ничего не понятно. Опишите подробнее какие данные и какие условия на входе.

Comment: у вас циклы разной длины - `6-0=6` и `10-6=4` , такое без "костылей" не объединяется, да надо ли оно вам на самом деле? опишите более общую задачу, может вы не с того конца подошли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите вывести

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 7 8 9

То можно писать так

```
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
     Console.WriteLine(i - i/7);
```

Ну или так.

```
for(int i=0, j=0; i < 11; i++, j= i > 6?i-1:i)
     Console.WriteLine(j);
```

Comment: да, а как сделать чтобы i-i/7 были бы в одно строку 
может быть i<11&&i-i/7;i++)  ???
и почему именно 7

Comment: В строку условия пишется именно условие, можно конечно изменить строку следующего элемента, но зачем? Так проще.

Comment: Зачем ? Мне так надо, в одну строку от и до ...от и до, мне одна строка а не две надо, перепишите пж в одну строку)

Comment: а если мне надо только "i" использовать а не "j" , то как быть ?

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно два цикла объединить в один, то это можно сделать с помощью LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (int i in Range(0, 6).Concat(Range(6, 4)))
            WriteLine(i);
        ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Если непременно нужно слово `and`, то можно ввести дополнительную функцию:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Linq.Enumerable;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foreach (int i in and(Range(0, 6), Range(6, 4)))
            WriteLine(i);
        ReadKey();
    }

    static IEnumerable<T> and<T> (params IEnumerable<T>[] es) => es.SelectMany(e => e);
}
```

Инфиксную запись, к сожалению, обеспечить будет проблематично.

Comment: а разве вообще возможно сейчас инфиксную сделать?

Comment: А если `Range(0, 6).And(Range(6, 4))` (через extension method)?

Comment: @Grundy не, нельзя инфиксную, если оператор не определен в языке, то создать его не получится, можно только перегрузить существующие, ну или определить если не был определен для конкретного типа, но новые значки для операторов это не добавит. Если только цепочку вызовов, как предложил VladD, считать инфиксной

Comment: @rdorn а можно от наследоваться или создать свой класс который реализует эти операции?

Comment: @pavel для собственного кастомного типа можно переопределить любой из существующих операторов. Создать новый - нет